# Config changes not being picked up when running test coverage with Jest

Tags: jestjs

I am looking for a way to exclude entire folders/files from my testing coverage with Jest. I have gone through the official Jest documentations several times, but have been unable to get it to work. I've come to the conclusion that maybe my jest.config.js isn't being picked up, because no matter what changes I make to the `collectCoverageFrom` or `testPathIgnorePatterns` fields, the test coverage return does not change, and it includes everything, even the things I am trying to exclude. Here is my test coverage script in the package.json:

```
"test-coverage": "npm test --config='jest.config.js' --coverage "
```

and here is my jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>', '<rootDir>/src', '<rootDir>/tests'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['./src/**/*.{js, jsx}', '!**/node_modules/**', '!**/vendor/**'],
  coverageDirectory: './coverage',
}
```

For the files I am excluding, I am just using this format: `!src/folder/file.js` as per the [official jest
documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array).

Any help appreciated.

**Things I did to troubleshoot:**

1. I added the path to the Jest config into the test-coverage command, but that was unsuccessful.
2. I have set the  `collectCoverage` field above to true, no success.
3. I added the jest config to the actual package.json, but even that
   did not change anything. Here is the format for it inside my
   package.json:

```
"jest": { 
   "roots": ["<rootDir>", "<rootDir>/src","<rootDir>/tests"],
   "testEnvironment": "jsdom",  
   "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/"],   
   "collectCoverage": true,
   "collectCoverageFrom": ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx}","!**/node_modules/**","!**/vendor/**"],   
   "coverageDirectory": "./coverage" 
}
```

Comment: Is your file named "jest.config.js" or "jest.config.json"? In your "test-coverage" example you specify the config as "jest.config.js" but when you shared your file you have it named "jest.config.json". If they are different, that could be your issue...I find it odd that putting it directly in your package.json doesn't work though. That's the way I have my project set up and it doesn't have any issues.

Comment: Whoops, typo. Thanks for catching that. The config is jest.config.js and I have the test-coverage script set to jest.config.js as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit confused why it wouldn't pick up directly from my package.json. I am wondering if I am formatting it wrong.

Comment: The only thing I see odd with your format when you had it in your `package.json` is that you aren't quoting the keys and that you are using single quotes rather than double quotes for what you do have quoted. If you did, in fact, have it in the format you have above, it would have definitely not worked.

Comment: I double quoted the keys and it still didn't pick up unfortunately.